# How do I apply decorators to a superclass's methods?

Tags: python, decorator, metaclass

Suppose I have a python class

```
class Foo(object):
    def method1(self, x):
        print("method1 called with %s" %(x,))

    def method2(self, x):
        print("method2 called with %s" %(x,))
```

and a decorator

```
def myDecorator(func):
    newFunc = someModificationOf(func)
    return newFunc
```

I would like to be able to subclass `Foo` and somehow in the subclass definition indicate that I want `myDecorator` to be applied to some subset of the methods inherited from `Foo`. For example, my subclass could like like

```
class Baz(Foo):
    methodsToDecorate = ['method2']
```

Is this possible?

**What I tried:**

I thought I could do this with a metaclass:

```
class Baz(Foo):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
    methodsToDecorate = ['method2']

class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, d):
        for m in d['methodsToDecorate']:
            d[m] = myDecorator(d[m])
        return type(name, bases, d)
```

However, it doesn't work because `'method2'` is not in the dictionary passed into the metaclass's `__new__` method, so we get a `KeyError`. I like the idea of using a metaclass because it allows the decorator to manipulate functions, rather than methods, which seems like a good simplification.

Comment: I don't think you really want to decorate the base class methods just because some subclass has been created, do you? That would affect every instance of the base class, and of all of its independent subclasses, which would lead to very confusing code. Do you just want to override the methods, in your subclass, with decorated versions of the superclass methods? Because that's a whole lot simpler, and a lot more sensible.

Comment: As a side note, you're using Python 2-style metaclasses, but Python 3-style `print` methods. Which language are you actually using?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7, but am in the habit of using Python 3.x print statements since they work in both.

Comment: OK, cool. Just wanted to check. I've seen people asking "why does my metaclass not work" because they were trying to use `__metaclass__` in 3.x…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming what you *really* want to do is not decorate the base class's copies of those methods, but decorate new overriding copies of those methods in the subclass.

If so, that's easy. The methods don't exist in the dictionary passed to the metaclass because they're not defined in the class definition, they're inherited from the bases. Which the metaclass *also* has access to. So:

```
def __new__(cls, name, bases, d):
    def find_method(m):
        for base in bases:
            try:
                return getattr(base, m)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        raise AttributeError("No bases have method '{}'".format(m))
    for m in d['methodsToDecorate']:
        d[m] = myDecorator(find_method(m))
    return type(name, bases, d)
```

If you really do want to reach into the base class and replace its methods, you can of course do that using the same trick. Just return the base along with the found method, so you can `setattr` it.

---

You asked for overriding a method *in the base class*. But what if the method actually comes from a more distant ancestor? Then this will still work… but it may not work the way you wanted. If you have multiple bases that share a common ancestor, calling `getattr` on each direct base will search that common ancestor once per base, but calling `getattr` on the new class will only search it once at the end.

As user2357112 points out in a comment, if what you want to override is "whatever would have been called if I didn't override anything", you can do that by constructing the new class *first*, then modifying it after the fact, by calling `getattr` on the result class itself. In 2.x, this does mean you have to deal with unbound methods instead of functions (in 3.x, that's not an issue, because unbound methods just *are* functions), but the benefits probably outweigh the cost.

Comment: Might be better to create the class, then decorate the methods so you follow the MRO properly.

Comment: @user2357112: Agreed, but that seems like a _separate_ improvement to what he was trying to do, rather than the one he was asking about, so… maybe better to leave it in a comment instead of putting it in the answer? What do you think?

Comment: @abarnert: Perfect. Also, thanks for understanding what I meant rather than what I said :)

Comment: @user2357112: On second thought, I think maybe it does belong in the answer. Either way, thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: @abarnert: I think for python 2.x you should change myDecorator(find_method(m)) to myDecorator(find_method(m).im_func). Does that make sense? I think this fixes the issue of unbound methods versus functions.